# Set an objects' property only in business logic?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee

if I have an object, eg

```
class Car {
  boolean sold = false;
}
```

and the object is present in the view layer, which is better if I want to change that value: change the `sold` value in a view class like

```
class CarView {
  Car car;

  onButtonAction() {
      car.setSold(true);
      //or: carService.sellCar(car)
  }
}
```

or

use a backend service like `carService.sellCar(car);` where

```
class CarService {
    sellCar(car) {
        car.setSold(true);
    }
}
```

In which layer should I place those actions? And would it be a mistake from design point of view to apply object changes like this within the view class?

Answer (score 1):

Design always means to find an optimum when you have several options that exclude each other. So there can never be a correct design, it can always only be better or worse regarding your design goals (which are also not universally valid/good).

If the service changes often or your UI needs to feed data to several similar services, create a service because otherwise, you'll find yourself changing the view all the time. Another good reason is when the service is pluggable (i.e. customers can configure the application to use one of several predefined services).

If you find yourself writing hundreds of services and each is used exactly once, each has only a single method, etc. you're probably wasting your time.